# API method to check for Zip file validity - zip is not closed after?

Tags: php, zip

we are using an API method to check for Zip file validity.
That method works like that:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CHECKCONS);
if ($res !== TRUE) {
    switch($res) {
        case ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP:
            die('not a zip archive');
        case ZipArchive::ER_INCONS :
            die('consistency check failed');
        case ZipArchive::ER_CRC :
            die('checksum failed');
        default:
            die('error ' . $res);
    }
}
```

But `$zip` is not closed after opening. So my question is - if `$zip` is not closed explicitly, does it automatically close when script is ended?
If it is not closed automatically, does it exist anywhere in system after script has ended?
Does it take any space or other resources on server after that?

Best regards,
Luke

Answer (score 0):

It will still be opened unless you do `$zip->close();` or close the script.

Comment: Ok, so until $zip->close(); files are physically located on my server, correct?

Comment: @LukDan `close()` closes the file handle. It doesn't remove files.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález ok, thank you. 
I would like to know if it is OK to leave $zip opened without closing it? Will it take any extra server resources or have any other side effects if it is not closed using $zip->close()?

Comment: It will still be in use, that means other scripts wont be able to do anything with it and will most likely use resources.

Comment: @Timberman, do you know for how long it will be in use? Will it close automatically when the script ends?